# Interactive filters on wordpress

Tags: plugins

I am going to use FacetWP plugin. I would like to filter different Ingredients in recipe database, so that user can find out the recipe according to the available Ingredients. 
Question is that is there any option to let the user decide about the filtering roles? 
For example, if he has the A,B and C ingredietlnt, during the selection of them for filtering, he can define the system shows the recipes which have Both A and B or C ingredient 
(A&B) or C.

Sites like supercook, if we select both Egg and mushroom as example, will show the recipes which include egg or mushroom, and there is no option to select the one which has both. 
I would like to have more freedom for moving step forward.

Thanks for your time and support.
Best Regards

Comment: Have you asked the publisher of the plugin?

Comment: Third party plugins such as Facet WP are offtopic here, you should contact Facet WP support and communities for help and advice with Facet WP